# How can I Export a datatable to an excel sheet with user-defined row no of the excel sheet from c#?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

How can I Export a datatable to an excel sheet with user-defined row no of the excel sheet from c#?

[image]

Comment: Explain more on what you have tried already and what exactly it is you want to achieve.

Comment: i need to know only how can we insert value to the next row if the excel is filled with values i will upload an image for your reference , i used to export all data from datatable to excel first time

Comment: here you can see till 14th row value is there, so inned to inser the next 10 value from 15th row till 24th row

Comment: The problem here is that you've not even tried to have a go (Or not shown any evidence of it). This isn't a code writing service, have a go yourself and when you come across a concrete problem, feel free to then ask a quesiton. A good tool for this kind of thing is [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Darken, i used several methods after that only i came to ask the quetion. i get the row no , so next thing i need to write from that row No. in the same excel sheet

Comment: i tried this one i got the answer.. for those who make me a downvote my question .. do not make others fool ok.. there is a possible to do the way. first you should think the route and work

Comment: my answer  i posted as solution go and check and then if it is worong put down vote my question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this one I got the answer. For those who downvoted my question, there is a possible to do the way. First you should think the route and work

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet mWSheet1;
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
public static void ReadExistingExcel()
{
   string path = @"C:\Tool\Reports1.xls";
   oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
   oXL.Visible = true;
   oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
   mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
   //Get all the sheets in the workbook
  mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
   //Get the allready exists sheet
   mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1");
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range= mWSheet1.UsedRange;
   int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
   int rowCount= range.Rows.Count;
   for (int index = 1; index < 15; index++)
   {
      mWSheet1.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = rowCount +index;
      mWSheet1.Cells[rowCount + index, 2] = "New Item"+index;
   }
   mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,    Missing.Value,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
   Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
   mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
   mWSheet1 = null;
   mWorkBook = null;
   oXL.Quit();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
   GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
   GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: this is the exact method to do the way i found the solution with above answer

Comment: thnaks you swetha this is what i am trying to get for past few weeks.. now i got the real solution for my requirement ..

Answer (score -1):

This is how I currently write a datatable to an excel spreadsheet, see if it fits your needs. Can you please elaborate on " userdefined row no of the excel sheet from c#?" and I will try help further.
 This will put the spreadsheet in the active directory, the same place the .exe of your program is.

```
public void ExportToExcel(DataTable table, string filename)
    {
        var lines = new List<string>();

        string[] columnNames = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName).ToArray();

        var header = string.Join(",", columnNames);
        lines.Add(header);

        var valueLines = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
        lines.AddRange(valueLines);
        File.WriteAllLines(filename + ".csv", lines);

        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("File Successfully exported! Open now?", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string path = "...";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i will not provide from which row onwards you can insert

Comment: Why not let the user set the row in a text box. Get the value. Then remove the rows in the datatable then pass the datatable to the above.

Comment: so u r making the size of datatable too high. to avoid that only am trying to solve like this

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a for loop. Set the counter to 0 and the upper limit to the value the user has entered. Then for the row[count] remove the row. Then pass the datatable to the above.

Comment: i dinot understand ur idea

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
`If you not clear in this coding, then go through this link`

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/deveshomar/exporting-datatable-to-excel-in-c-sharp-using-interop/

```
private void exportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{

    /*Set up work book, work sheets, and excel application*/
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    try
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook obook = oexcel.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet osheet = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet();


      //  obook.Worksheets.Add(misValue);

        osheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)obook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        int colIndex = 0;
        int rowIndex = 1;

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            colIndex++;
            osheet.Cells[1, colIndex] = dc.ColumnName;
        }
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            rowIndex++;
            colIndex = 0;

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                colIndex++;
                osheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex] = dr[dc.ColumnName];
            }
        }

        osheet.Columns.AutoFit();
        string filepath = "C:\\Temp\\Book1";

        //Release and terminate excel

        obook.SaveAs(filepath);
        obook.Close();
        oexcel.Quit();
        releaseObject(osheet);

        releaseObject(obook);

        releaseObject(oexcel);          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        oexcel.Quit();          
    }
}
    private void releaseObject(object o) 
    { 
      try 
       { 
          while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0) { } 
       } 
      catch 
        { 
        } 
      finally 
         { 
       o = null;
          }
         }
```

Comment: it is not inserting the value to the specified row