# how to change excel column format in text when i use streamwriter to create a excel file in c#

Tags: c#

how to change excel column format in text when i use streamwriter to create a excel file in c#
here is my code

```
           `string p1 = @"C:\\EXCEL\\DATA\\data" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss") + ".xls";
            System.IO.FileInfo objFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(p1);
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(p1);
            cmd = new OracleCommand("here is my query",con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter AD = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.Fill(DS);
            for (int i = 0; i < (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count); i++)
                 {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                         {
                           if (dt.Rows[i][j] != null)
                               {
                                 wr.Write(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]).ToString() + "\t");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                  wr.Write("\t");
                                }
                            }
                            wr.WriteLine();
                         }`
```

please suggess
thanks in advance

Comment: {wr.Write(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]).ToString() + "\t");
                                }-> to this ->{
                                 wr.Write(" ' "+Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]).ToString() + "\t");
                                }

Comment: ` wr.Write(" ' "+Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i][j]).ToString() + "\t"); ` it works but the value is shown this format    '00987655     i want 00987655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i put this as second answer

```
private void sample()
            {

                string p1 = @"C:\\EXCEL\\DATA\\data" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss") + ".xls";
                //System.IO.FileInfo objFileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(p1);
                //StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(p1);
                cmd = new OracleCommand("here is my query", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                OracleDataAdapter AD = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                da.Fill(DS);

                ExportToExcel(DS.Tables[0], p1);
            }   

            public void ExportToExcel( DataTable dtCollection,string savingFileName)
            {
                var ds = dtCollection;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet objWorkSheet1 = null;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application objExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application { Visible = false };
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks objWorkbooks = objExcel.Workbooks;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objWorkbook = objWorkbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets objSheets = objWorkbook.Worksheets;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range objCells;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myCell;
                var iCurrentRow = 10;
                var dt = ds;
                int columnsCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                objWorkSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)(objSheets[1]);
                objCells = objWorkSheet1.Cells;

                for (var h = 0; h < dt.Columns.Count; h++)
                {
                    myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[iCurrentRow, h + 1];
                    myCell.Value2 = dt.Columns[h].ColumnName;
                }
                iCurrentRow++;
                for (var r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
                {
                    for (var c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
                    {
                        if (dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "String" || dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
                        {
                            myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
                            myCell.Value2 = "'" + dt.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            myCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)objCells[r + iCurrentRow, c + 1];
                            myCell.Value2 = dt.Rows[r][c];
                        }
                    }
                }
                objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit();
                objWorkSheet1.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                objWorkbook.SaveAs(savingFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                objWorkbook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                objExcel.Quit();
            }
```

Comment: an unhandled exception of type 'system.type.runtime.interopservice.COMException' occured

Comment: add interop services in the reference

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is already added in the reference  this error is occured when the file is saving,error- the file could not be accessed...............here ,                   `objWorkbook.SaveAs(savingFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                Missing.Value, Missing.Value);`

Comment: The file name is not passing to the parameter , savingFileName, check this parameter is having the file name or not.

Comment: yes parameter is defined    `public void ExportToExcel( DataTable dtCollection,string savingFileName)`

Comment: can  you cone on discussion tab in the  Stackoverflow so i can able to solve your problem easly

Comment: or please mail ur code .. sterday i already mailed u the solution . replay back on the email so i can serch it and solve the issue

Comment: R u using the trial version of microsoft office

Comment: Use this instead of that excelWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\MyExcelTestTest", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel12, 
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, false, 
      Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
      System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

Comment: thanks it's working but the special character ( ' ) this is hidden, is it's problem for import the data from excel to sqlserver?

Comment: no, it will not u can remove that charater ' during exports , which i already given one solution

Comment: Welcome , feel happy ask questions

Comment: i have already a excel format, can i update excel sheet instead creating the excel sheet using your solution code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code you will get the solution

```
 for (var r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
 {
   for (var c = 0; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
     {
       if (dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "String" || dt.Columns[c].DataType.Name == "DateTime")
          wr.Write( "'" + dt.Rows[r][c].ToString().Trim());
        else
          wr.Write( dt.Rows[r][c]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: in excel the zero to shown as first it should have any character in frond of it like ',+ or - then only the zero will shown in the first e.g like '00978654, or +00976543 or -00876543 other wise the first value is zero it will automatically removed by from excel cell.

Comment: during importing this you can use if strement to remove the first charater " ' " from the string and convert to number .

Comment: which you need ,  import the data from excel to SQL server. or export from sqlserver to excel

Comment: smile, what is it copy paste what the exact need. from both of these u need both or only one

Comment: ok, for this you can do one thing export the data from Sql server to Excel by varchar formart,  then from excel to sql server you can export from varchar to integer format. from the above code reverse

Comment: s, then you importing the data from excel through code , if from code you can use convert the column with convert. to int

Comment: ok i will provide a code to export the data to excel .. you can refer thi s code and try. all data to excel in text format. ok chekc with this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389678/how-can-i-export-a-datatable-to-an-excel-sheet-with-userdefined-row-no-of-the-ex/39424040#39424040

Comment: go with above link you will understand

Comment: come on discussion

Comment: provide your code how you export value from sql server to Excel

Comment: see my second solution so you can easly convert data from SqlServer to Excel

Comment: the above code will help you to from sql server to EXCEL from excel to SQL server i will provide to your mail